# php using zend framework does not print html properly

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, printing, echo

I am using zend framework...

so I have the following code in display.php:

```
<?php
    class display{

           public static function displayYeaa(){
                ?>
                  <?php
                    self::displayHaHa('lol','LOL');
                  ?>
                <?php
            }

           public static function displayHaHa($type = 'lol',$text = 'LOL'){
              ?>
                 <a class="like" href="javascript:;" id="<?php echo $type; ?>Asdf" class="hahha">
                 </a>
              <?php
           }

    }
?>
```

then I call the code from a zend framework view .phtml file...

```
<?php
    require_once('display.php');
    display::displayYeaa();
?>
```

but the output is really weird:

```
<a id="lolAsdf" href="javascript:;" class="like">
         </a>
```

notice that the id is outputted BEFORE the href, class="like" ends up being last, and class="hahha" ends up not being printed at all (I know that you shouldn't have 2 class tags, but it's still interesting why it's not printing the second class)...

anybody knows what's wrong? I know the code is mumble jumble, but this is more for experimentation purpose and it still baffles me why it's not printing as I'm telling it to...

Comment: Omg, such a terrible code :-S

Comment: The Firebug / Chrome DOM inspector is no replacement for looking at the actual source

Comment: why is this filed under zend-framework? If you are doing this project in zf, try to keep your code structured using default conventions.. Even if the framework was causing your problems. It would be impossible to debug or to hold the framework responsible when you are operating so far outside convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually view the page source as opposed to looking at your browser's DOM inspector, you would see that it is in fact rendering as expected.

Comment: lol so is firebug the one doing the whole shuffling business?